# Homebrew - Python3.7 replace Python3.6.5 if you brew install opencv2

Tags: homebrew

I installed Python 3.6 using a direct link (`brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rbbrew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb`), since Brew now install by default 3.7 version, if I use `brew install python3`

Although if I install OpenCv2 from Brew; I get also Python 3.7, and that version get linked as default, moving 3.6 aside. I did try to `brew link` the previous version, but then when I import cv2, I get an error that the package does not exist.

If I run `brew install opencv` It tell me that the packages are already installed; so Python 3.6 can't import it, but 3.7 can.

I thought it is a problem with `PATH` but even that does not seem to have effect.

is there a way to tell brew to not update python when installing new packages? I am OK with 3.7 being installed; but I would like to be able to use OpenCV2 from both; while now I can only import it using 3.7 and not 3.6

Answer (score 0):

`brew pin python` will prevent it from being upgraded. OpenCV will need to be installed with `--build-from-source` since the bottle is built and tested against the latest python formula.